# WinPE Powershell prompts inside the PS window vs box with choices (Preferred)

Tags: powershell, prompt, sccm, winpe

I am making a prompt window which has buttons.  The script runs and opens a selection box which is preferred, however when I try using the same method in winpe using the serviceui.exe, it keeps the selections in the PS window.

[image]
I am not sure if I am using the appropriate session perhaps, which may be why the image given below does not show up vs the PS window.  This code may be incorrect as I am patching this one issue at a time.  My initial issue is figuring out how to show the choice box below, then I can focus on the code, but open to all suggestions! Thanks so much for checking it out!

The abbreviated code:

```
$Title = "Workgroup Machine Destination"
$Info = "Please select the location where this machine will belong:" 
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&Selection1", "&Selection2", "&Selection3")
[int]$defaultchoice = 0
$opt = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title , $Info , $Options,$defaultchoice)
switch($opt)
{
0 { $apw = 'pwd1'}
1 { $apw = 'pwd2'}
2 { $apw = 'pwd3'}
}
$apw = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment 
$apw.Value("OSDLocalAdminPassword") = $apw
```

The script which I run via cmdline is:

```
ServiceUI.exe -process:TSProgressUI.exe %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File PCLocation.ps1
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it keeps the selections in the PS window?

Comment: Based on your syntax, you should be able to use the OSDLocalAdminPassword variable now.  Make sure you don't include extra SCCM steps of 'Initialize'.  If you do this, you'll lose the changes you've made with this script.

Comment: I had to remove the windows style hidden syntax to see that the entries show in the powershell window itself during the task sequence.  It was originally getting hung waiting on input from the powershell window (which was hidden originally).  Thanks for the response.  I don't have any 'Initialize' scripts that I am aware of.